# How do I submit suggestions to the CSS spec?

Tags: css, w3c, specifications

Recently I've wanted to do a number of things using CSS only to find that the best solution is to use Javascript. This has made me wonder, does anyone here know how to go about making development suggestions to be implemented into CSS 3 spec?

It would be great if we could get some sort of feature request/vote based system going that the w3 guys could at least look at. I know, as a programmer, I often overlook obvious things when I'm deep into something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably subscribe to the [www-style mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/) of W3C

> This mailing list is for technical discussion on Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) and its specifications. All posts to this list must be about the development of the CSS specification itself. This list is also the preferred place for discussing working drafts that are published by W3C's CSS Working Group.